# Null json_decode with Gson encoding

Tags: php, android, json, null, gson

I have a Java method where I encode (using GSON) and send json data to my php scripts in the server:

```
public JSONObject storeStadistics(Integer user_id, ArrayList<Question> questionList) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(questionList, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Question>>() {}.getType());
    if(!element.isJsonArray()) {
        System.out.println("ERROR parsing in storeStadistics");
        return null;
    }

    JsonArray jsArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    JSONObject jsQuestions = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsQuestions.put("questions", jsArray);
        jsQuestions.put("user", user_id);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("ERROR in storeStadistics:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<BasicNameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", storeStadistics_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("object", jsQuestions.toString()));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(server+"playManager.php", params);

    return json;
}
```

Once I am in my php script and runs the proper section of my code, I call my function like this:

```
$result = $db->storeStadistics($_POST['object']);
```

And inside storeStadistics:

```
public function storeStadistics($object) {
    $object = json_decode($object, false); //true doesn't work either

    ...
}
```

**The result of this decoding is NULL** but I don't realize why is it. If I print $object before decoding I get this:

```
string(242) "{"user":1,"questions":"[{\"mArticle\":\"\",\"mDefinition\":\"Was macht eine Person, die schlecht über eine andere Person spricht? Sie...\",\"mName\":\"tratschen\",\"mId\":27,\"mPuntuacion\":0,\"mClue\":false,\"mSuccess\":true,\"mTries\":6}]"}"
```

Which contains all the info that I need.
Basically it is an string whose encoding would transform it into an object with two fields: user_id and an array, that I would like to parse with a foreach loop.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your object class ? GSON is very particular about variable names. I can help if you share that. I am doing something very similar right now. The `Question.class`

Comment: you are mixin two APIS GSON and org.json ... so `jsQuestions.put("questions", jsArray);` becomes `jsQuestions.put("questions", jsArray.toString());` as you can see, on server side, `questions` is a string not an array ...

Comment: Selvin answer is correct. Thanks